# Go interfaces: is not net.Conn a io.ReadWriteCloser?

Tags: go, network-programming, go-interface

I have a question about the uses of interfaces in go. I am still learning the language, so please forgive me if it is a stupid question.

I am playing with a little application that accept and handle TCP connections. Because I want to test the business logic and not the network magic, I am trying to keep it a little bit abstract using interfaces (so I can simulate net.Conn object using simple `io.ReadWriteCloser` objects).

Here is my problem:

```
type Accepter interface {
    Accept() (io.ReadWriteCloser, error)
}

func NewTCPAccepter(address string) (Accepter, error) {
    accepter, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return accepter, err
}
```

The error I see is:

```
net.Listener does not implement Accepter (wrong type for Accept method)
                have Accept() (net.Conn, error)
                want Accept() (io.ReadWriteCloser, error)
```

What I do not understand is why this is happening, because checking the documentation and the net lib source code, I see that `net.Conn` is actually implementing `io.ReadWriteCloser`.

What is my mistake? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `Accepter` "dictates" the return type to be `io.ReadWriteCloser`. `net.Listener.Accept()` returns `net.Conn`. Types must match exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that stupid questions exist. If there is an honest question, there is an urge for knowledge, and it cannot be stupid by definition :)

Go relies on method signature to decide if two interfaces are the same. You cannot say that two method signatures are equal if they return essentially different types.

P.S.
If I express my opinion, I don't think your `Accepter` abstraction is sound. I am struggling to explain what it does. Coming up with a good abstraction is hard, and I am pretty sure that the existing abstractions are already enough to do what you want -- test your business logic.

Let's say your business logic parses a JSON document and converts it to a human-readable text. You can pack it to a function with the following signature:

```
func DescribeDocument(src io.Reader, dst io.Writer) error {
    ...
}
```

You can pass an object that implements the `net.Conn` interface to this function in a production code or the `bytes.Buffer` object in a test code. No need to invent unnecessary abstractions :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what the issue is:

```
net.Listener does not implement Accepter (wrong type for Accept method)
                have Accept() (net.Conn, error)
                want Accept() (io.ReadWriteCloser, error)
```

You have a different return time than what your interface has defined. Take a second look at the error message `have` and `want` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the error message, my doubt is about the way go handles the interfaces: a `net.Conn` object should be - by definition - a `io.ReadWriteCloser` interface too. Because of that I do not understand why the compiler complains. Whatever operation I want to perform on a ReadWriteCloser (RWC) object, I should be able to do also on a net.Conn implementation. Just to give you an example: I can create a channel of RWC and passing there a net.Conn without any issue; I was expecting the same here.